# Google Drive and .NET WinForms

Tags: .net, winforms, google-drive-api

Cannot connect my Windows Form Application with GoogleDrive via Drive API.

I have created a project on https://console.developers.google.com/, enabled Drive API, generated Client ID, Service e-mail and *.p12 key.

I instantiate DriveService by this method:

```
private const string SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "SERVICE_EMAIL@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
private const string SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = @"PATH_.p12";

static DriveService BuildService()
{
    X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

    ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
    {
        User = "OWNER_EMAIL@GMAIL.COM",
        Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.DriveFile }
    }.FromCertificate(certificate));

    var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = "Drive API Sample",
    });

    return service;
}
```

And try to upload files by this method:

```
public static void upload(String filepath)
{
    File body = new File();
    body.Title = "test";
    body.Description = "Some description";
    body.MimeType = "text/plain";

    byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
    System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

    FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = BuildService().Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain");
    request.Upload();

    File file = request.ResponseBody;
}
```

However, request.ResponceBody is always null. What do I miss ?

Comment: You might want to remove personal information from this code...

Comment: I do not think, someone will able to exploit it, but I did anyway.

Comment: You should try a simple file reading / download before upload

Comment: @Nicolas R, I can not read or download files before I upload them.

Comment: Can't you just upload a file manually (not with your code)? It would be way easier to try download first, which needs less parameters, before trying a more complex operation

Comment: @Nicolas R No, I can not. Service accounts accessible only programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using System.IO;
using System.Web;

//...

    public static DriveService BuildService()
    {
        string SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = "XXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
        string SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH = @"\YYYYYYY.p12";

        return new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
            {
                Scopes = new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive }
            }.FromCertificate(new X509Certificate2(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable))),
            ApplicationName = "applicationName"
        });
    }

    public static void insertFile(String filePath)
    {
        Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
        body.Title = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
        body.MimeType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filePath);

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));
        FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = BuildService().Files.Insert(body, stream, body.MimeType);
        request.Upload();
    }
```